# domainruntime() and CD('/') issue

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

I created a python file and created another shell file to prepare the environment to run the python script. Below is part of the python script including two functions and the error code.
I have the following Python code

```
def getState():
    print "Getting Servers status..."
    cd ('/')
    allModules = cmo.getServers()
    domainRuntime()
    cnt = 0
    modules = ""
    for moduleName in allModules:
        currentModule = moduleName.getName()
        print ":: Current Server Name = " + currentModule
        cd ('/')
        slrBean = cmo.lookupServerLifeCycleRuntime(currentModule)
        serverState = slrBean.getState()
        print "Current Server status is: " + serverState
        if serverState == "RUNNING" and (currentModule.find("amq"))  != -1:
            print "Shutting down AMQ managed server"
            shutdown(currentModule, 'Server', 'true', 1000, force="true", block='true')
            undeployApp()
            ds(currentModule,moduleName)
        elif (currentModule.find("amq"))  != -1:
            try:
                print "ElseIf"
                undeployApp()
            except Exception, e:
                print e
            ds(currentModule,moduleName)
    if (cnt == 0):
        modules = currentModule
    else:
        modules = modules + "," + currentModule
    cnt = cnt + 1
    return modules


def ds(myModule,mo):
    print "Deleting AMQ server"
    cd('/Servers/'+myModule)
    cmo.setCluster(None)
    cmo.setMachine(None)
    editService.getConfigurationManager().removeReferencesToBean(getMBean('/Servers/'+myModule))
    cd('/')
    cmo.destroyServer(getMBean('/Servers/'+myModule))
```

I am getting this error

```
Deleting AMQ server
This Exception occurred at Mon Oct 07 08:24:52 PDT 2019.
javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: com.bea:Name=gems,Type=DomainRuntime:Servers
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/x/home/pegaadmin/test.py", line 233, in ?
  File "/x/home/pegaadmin/test.py", line 107, in getState
  File "/x/home/pegaadmin/test.py", line 118, in ds
  File "<iostream>", line 164, in cd
  File "<iostream>", line 552, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error cding to the MBean
```

Configuration failied, aborting .....

I can't figure out the domainruntime() and the correct path CD('/')
any solutions and suggestions please ?!

Comment: Can you try to change the mbean tree before your cd('/Servers/'+myModule) ?
As you stop your server before deleting it, you may have to go back to the domain configuration mbean tree before deleting the server.    
`domainConfig()  

cd('/Servers/'+myModule)  
...`

Comment: it did not work. but I am seeing a different error now as below

Comment: Undeploy Successfull
Deleting AMQ Serverstage2cpp084_amqcluster1_amqapp2
Location changed to serverRuntime tree. This is a read-only tree with DomainMBean as the root.
For more help, use help('domainConfig')

Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/x/home/pegaadmin/D.py", line 212, in ?
  File "/x/home/pegaadmin/D.py", line 102, in getServerNames
  File "/x/home/pegaadmin/D.py", line 153, in ds
```

Comment: at weblogic.management.jmx.ExceptionMapper.matchJMXException(ExceptionMapper.java:74)
        at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:508)
        at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:382)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.setCluster(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

Comment: i see, if you update the domain config you have to change to the edit mbean tree :   
edit()  
startEdit()  
...  
save()  
activate()

Comment: You are right :) I have solved the issue. Thanks Emmanuel